# Can I make something tab/window scoped in JSF?

Tags: jsf-2.2

Is it possible for JSF to store some information specific to a tab or window?

For example, let's say that I have a page with a datatable and the user can manipulate attributes of that table (column visibility, sort order, row selection, etc).  The user clicks one of the entries to go to the entry's "view" page.  Then they navigate back to the datatable page.  They want their original datatable attributes set on that table.

But, if they open up that page in a different tab or window, they want to be able to manipulate attributes of that table on that tab independently.  Therefore, session-scoped is not an option.

Perhaps I could use a flow-scoped bean to do this?  Is that just abusing flow-scoped?  For example, the bean would actually never terminate.

I'm also open to hearing about how bad an idea this is...so any alternative ideas would also be welcome.

Comment: Take a look at https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/jsf.html#Scopes . Deltaspike offers a @WindowScope annotation.

Comment: @kev: does that work out well when response ends in a new window/tab? (target=_blank, ctrl+click, middleclick, URL copypaste, etc). Due to stateless nature of HTTP there's no bulletproof solution for this, or you must exclusively navigate by ajax and use a `@ViewScoped` (SPA, Single Page Application).

Comment: @BalusC can you give details? That's actually my problem if I have a bean as sessionScoped navigationController which has a Stack holding the navigation history, openening multiple tags will end up in wrong navigation because each tab would influence the stack.